# Swift: Local Date object and local timezone

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I've searched and searched, but most of the time posts talk about creating a localized string from a Date(). I need a date object to set a Timer to fire at the correct time.

I realize I might be missing something... This is the best I have so far:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let todayDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "05/21/18")!
print(todayDate)
```

Which outputs:

```
2018-05-21 07:00:00 +0000
```

**> Question:** Why is there the +0000 if I set the dateFormatter variable timeZone to .current?

**+ Update 01:**

Following @MadProgrammer's comments:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss z"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
let todayDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!

print(dateString)
print(todayDate)
```

Which Outputs, first one being correct:

```
05/21/18 19:29:19 PDT
2018-05-22 02:29:19 +0000
```

**> Question:** Why would creating a date from the dateFormatter.string(...) date object be so different?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That may be your current datetime translated to UTC. Is it `07:00` where you are?

Comment: `Date` doesn't have a concept of timezone, it's just a container for the number of seconds from a given point of time - that's why you have formatters

Comment: On my system, `todayDate` prints `2018-05-20 14:00:00 +0000` and `Date()` prints `2018-05-22 02:12:27 +0000`, but `TimeZone.current` prints `Australia/Melbourne` - the `Date` object seems to be maintained in UTC. Fun fact, if I use `MM/dd/yy HH:mm z` as the format, then `dateFormatter.string(from: Date())` prints `05/22/18 12:15 GMT+10`

Comment: The following article will help explain what you are seeing: http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html

Comment: Looks good @rmaddy I will dig into it, thank you

Comment: Your update and 2nd question are clearly covered in the link I provided. Your output is fine. They are the same dates, just shown from two different timezones.